# Lambdas and sums Python

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

```
def summation(calc_termo, linf, prox, lsup):
    soma = 0
    while linf <= lsup:
        soma = soma + calc_termo(linf)
        linf = prox(linf)
    return soma
summation(lambda x: summation(lambda x: x, 1, lambda x: x + 1, x),1, lambda x: x + 1, 5)
```

I'm having trouble to understand how this code works. I got this as an exercise from my university and I'm having some trouble understanding the code.

It seems to be the sum of the numbers between 1 to 5, but can't understand what `summation(lambda x: x, 1, lambda x: x + 1, x)` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd start by taking those arguments apart:

```
lambda x: summation(lambda x: x, 1, lambda x: x + 1, x)
```

Substitute those variables back into the the original functions and simplify it:

```
def inner_function(x):
    soma = 0
    linf = 1

    while linf <= x:
        soma += linf + 1
        linf += 1

    return soma
```

Simplify that a little more:

```
def inner_function(x):
    soma = 0

    for linf in range(1, x + 1):
        soma += linf

    return soma
```

And a little more:

```
inner_function = lambda x: sum(range(1, x + 1))
```

And some more:

```
inner_function = lambda x: x * (x + 1) / 2
```

Now your original function becomes:

```
def summation(calc_termo, linf, prox, lsup):
    soma = 0

    while linf <= lsup:
        soma = soma + calc_termo(linf)
        linf = prox(linf)

    return soma

summation(inner_function, 1, lambda x: x + 1, 5)
```

Or:

```
def summation(linf, prox, lsup):
    soma = 0

    while linf <= lsup:
        soma = soma + linf * (linf + 1) / 2
        linf = prox(linf)

    return soma

summation(1, lambda x: x + 1, 5)
```

You can take it from there. I got:

```
summation = lambda: sum(n * (n + 1) / 2 for n in range(6))
```

Which is equal to:

```
sum(sum(range(n + 1)) for n in range(6))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help it was really helpfull i can understand it better now

Answer (score 0):

The last line that you had trouble with could better be stated as:

```
summation(lambda x: summation(lambda y: y, 1, lambda z: z + 1, x),1, lambda w: w + 1, 5)
```

The lambdas don't all interfere with each other, if that's what you were confused about.